# How to connect to Kafka Mesos Framework from an application using Spring Cloud Stream?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, mesos, spring-cloud-stream

Having a [Mesos-Marathon](https://open.mesosphere.com/getting-started/install/) cluster in place and a [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) application with [Spring Cloud Stream](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/) that consumes a topic from [Kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/), we now want to integrate Kafka with the Mesos cluster. For this we want to install [Kafka Mesos Framework](https://github.com/mesos/kafka).

Right now we have the application.yml configuration like this:

```
---
spring:
  profiles: local-docker
  cloud:
      stream:
        kafka:
          binder:
            zk-nodes: 192.168.88.188
            brokers: 192.168.88.188
 ....
```

Once we have installed Kafka Mesos Framework,

> How can we connect to kafka from Spring Cloud Stream?

or more specifically

> How will be the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

The configuration properties look good. Do you have the host addresses correct.
For more info on the kafka binder config properties, you can refer here:

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/master/spring-cloud-stream-docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-stream-overview.adoc#kafka-specific-settings